# java.util.logger undefined for the type System.Logger

Tags: java, logging

I am new to java and trying to use the logger in java.util. I declare the logger like this snippet:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

referring to this website: https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/java-logging-basics/

What I did was:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EthicalEngine.class.getName());
```

However, it shows the error message

```
The method getLogger(String) is undefined for the type System.Logger
```

Here is part of my main class ( `EthicalEngine` ):

```
public class EthicalEngine {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EthicalEngine.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EthicalEngine ethicalEngine = new EthicalEngine();
    ethicalEngine.commandLineProcess();

}
```

Did I do anything wrong, or there is something that I missed? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing [`java.util.logging.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html), which is a logging framework added in Java 1.4, and [`java.lang.System.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.Logger.html), which is a logging facade added in Java 9.

- `java.util.logging.Logger` is created by the [`Logger.getLogger(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) method.
- `java.lang.System.Logger` is created by the [`System.getLogger​(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) method.

Since you are calling `Logger.getLogger()`, it means that you imported the wrong `Logger` type.

***Solution:*** Fix your `import` statement.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I choose to use the `system logger`. When I tried to import `java.util.logging.Logger`, it showed `The import java.util.logging.Logger collides with another import statement`. However, I didn't anything that is related to the logger, which confuses me.

Comment: @Woden If you added `import java.util.logging.Logger`, then you must remove `import java.lang.System.Logger`. You cannot import both at the same time, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: exactly, I did `import java.util.logging.Logger` only, and the message showed up.

Comment: @Woden Since the Guide you were following is about "the `java.util.logging` package", you should stick with that. Don't know why you would "choose to use the `system logger`", since that has nothing to do with the Guide you were following.

Comment: @Woden Obviously not, since it explicitly says "collides with another import statement", so you do have another `import` statement importing a `Logger` type.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll check carefully. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import java.lang.System.Logger;
```

with

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

to remove the error.